# Align text in adjacent table cells with different sized borders?

Tags: html, css

I need help with the following code that works perfectly in Foxfire and -- surprise -- awfully in IE9.

In FF it produces a two-color band (table row) across the page about 25px high.
(I used a lot of junk background colors just to see where gaps existed.  And I know I can get the same effect in all css ... BUT there are other Cells I need to add to the right later that I have never been able to render in css, so I gave up and fled to a "simple" table row for now.)

The table is contained in a div with class="tabs-block">.
(That was necessesary to to force the table to be 100% wide.  For some reason the same setting when put in an id instead of a class would not work. Don't know why.)

The left half of the row (Cell 1) is
--  an empty cell (no content, font-size set to 0px)
--  it has a 25px white border on bottom and 25px blue on right (none on top or left)
--  it has an ORANGE  with a white background that shouldn't be seen because there isn't any content, and if there was it would be 0pt high. In FF it doesn't show.  In IE9 it peeks out
on top that is a few pixels wide.  (Wish I could attach a screen shot but I'm too new.)

The right side of the band(Cell 2) is 
-- a cell with a a blue background
-- NO borders
-- And it contains a single link whose text is 12pt white

The White (Left)Bule (Right) Cells meet in the middle looking like they have a 45 degree line between between them.

PROBLEM:
FF aligns the link text at the BOTTOM of Cell 2.
IE9 aligns the link text with the empty text area of Cell 2, i.e. IE9 aligns the Cell 2 text with the TOP of Cell 1's border.  NOT the bottom of Cell 2.
That leaves a white space gap under Cell 2 = (25px minus 12pt) high.

After too many days of utter defeat, my eyes have crossed and help is welcome.

```
.tabs-block > table {
   background-color: white;
   text-align: right;
   width: 100%;}

table#tabs-table {
      border-collapse:collapse;
      width:100%;}

tr#tabs-row-1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  background-color:red;}

<div class="tabs-block" style='background-color: green;'>
  <table cellspacing = '0px'
         cellpadding = '0px'  
         id='tabs-table;'>
     <tr id='tabs-row-1'>          
       <td style='width:50%;
                  margin:0px;
                  padding:0px;
                  background-color: orange;
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-color: #000066 #000066 #FFFFFF red;
                  border-width: 0px 25px 25px 0px;'
                  class='text-blue-0'></td>            
       <td style='width:1px; 
                  margin:0px;
                  padding:0px;
                  border:0px;
                  background-color: #000066;
                  white-space:nowrap;'
                  class='title-white-12'>                         
         <a href='contact.jsp'  class='title-white-10'
            style='vertical-align:bottom;
               height:100%;
               background-color: #000066; 
               padding:0px;
               margin:0px; 
               border:0px;'>
           Contact Us
         </a>
      </td>     
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this code is burning a hole through my cerebral cortex.  if you can agree to ditch the table idea entirely i'd gladly help you.  if you're wondering why i say that - tables are formatted differently between browsers, especially IE.  I suggest using the industry-standard unformatted list `<ul><li><a></a></li><li>...` format to accomplish this.  But you really haven't said what you're using it for either so that's only my instinct.  If it's for a navigation bar/menu, then go with the list with `list-style: none;`

Comment: you'd stand a better chance of getting some help if you included a definition for all the styles used in the html, or set up a fiddle to show the problem.

Comment: My appologies, but I'm obviously new here, so not sure what a fiddle is.  But if you open this link: http://america-3.org:8080/ in FF and then in IE9 you will see my problem -- I'd love to be able to do the the top banner in css because I have the rest of the site almost 100% css ... but doing that banner in css defeated me. the little blue line from half way to the right margin wouldn't go.

Answer (score 0):

My eyes crossed just reading this. Assuming that your content is tabular data, and I'm not enabling you to layout a site with a table, the only way you're going to achieve any kind of vertical alignment with varying borders is by using `vertical-align: middle`.

Maybe not the kind of alignment you want, but it's your best shot. Kind of wondering why you need borders of different thickness on the same table, though. Simplifying your styles could fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks ... I needed the border to draw the 45 degree line.  To see my problem in real life, please look at http://america-3.org:8080/  (my dedicated serve on eApps, so its safe w/o advertising junk).  Try FF first ... then IE9 and the problem should be obvious.  I couldn't solve it in css and now I'm failing with "simpler" tables.  I'm sure beginners are annoying, but I can't figure out how to start as an expert.

Comment: If you really, really want to get past this problem, then trust me when I say this: that 3d border design is not doing you any favors. Go with a solid color border and sleep better at night.

Comment: Grin ... I know you are right.  But this has become personal between me and IE.  I mean its not a very complicated look.  And its not like its a real tab.  AND FF has no problem with it.  And of course being new at this I haven't learned to be smart yet. So back to the battle.  It can't be impossible ... grin ... can't it?